# Definition of a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

I have it defined here that a field $\mathbb{F}$ consists of $\mathbb{F} = (\mathbb{F},+,0,1,\cdot)$
where

- $\mathbb{F}$ is a set
- $0,1 \in \mathbb{F}$, $0 \not = 1$
- $+$ is a mapping (addition), $+:\mathbb{F} \times \mathbb{F} \to \mathbb{F}$, $(x,y) \to x + y$
- $\cdot$ is a mapping (multiplication), $\cdot : \mathbb{F} \to \mathbb{F}$, $(x,y) \to x\cdot y$

such that the following axioms hold....

I am confused on what this means $+:\mathbb{F} \times \mathbb{F} \to \mathbb{F}$, $(x,y) \to x + y$ specifically what does $\mathbb{F} \times \mathbb{F} \to \mathbb{F}$ mean and what is the notation of $(x,y) \to x + y$?

Comment: Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28mathematics%29 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation. If you have any questions about these basic concepts, ask.

Comment: It means that $+$ is a function from the Cartesian product of $\Bbb F$ with itself to $\Bbb F$.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I don't really understand what the cartesian product does - could someone explain or should I make a new thread?

Comment: It's in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the notation
\begin{align*}
f : X&\to Y\\
x&\mapsto f(x)
\end{align*}
simply means that $f$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$ (i.e., you input values in $X$ and get values in $Y$), and the $x\mapsto f(x)$ tells you exactly what happens to an arbitrary element $x\in X$ ($x$ is sent to $f(x)$). In your case, the definition is telling you that given an element $(a,b)$ of $F\times F$ (equivalently, an ordered pair of elements in $F$), the function $+$ will send $(a,b)$ to $a+b$. Of course, this is not how we usually see addition of two elements in a field represented: rather than $+(a,b)$, we simply write $a+b$, although they are the same object.